# Use IF command from batch script with java

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

How do I use the `IF` command to respond on the output of the first java relay status command.

When you run the command the output is 0 when relay 1 is off. example below.

```
java -jar "C:\4_USB_Relay\DenkoviRelayCommandLineTool_10.jar" DAE001DQ 4 1 status

0
```

---

```
*REM Check_relay_status_output*

java -jar "C:\4_USB_Relay\DenkoviRelayCommandLineTool_10.jar" DAE001DQ 4 1 status

*REM Turn_relay_on*    
java -jar "C:\4_USB_Relay\DenkoviRelayCommandLineTool_10.jar" DAE001DQ 4 1 1

*REM Turn_relay_off*    
java -jar "C:\4_USB_Relay\DenkoviRelayCommandLineTool_10.jar" DAE001DQ 4 1 0
```

---

My idea is to use the one batch script to turn a relay on when its off and off when its on. :)

I'm not sure how to do this as its using a java command and I'm not sure how to capture the output.

All help would be greatly appreciated.
:)

Comment: I'd must move that on when off, off when on logic inside your Java, and have a invoked via 'toggle' command line argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this set errorlevel or the result is just printed? You can use [FIND](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) command and [conditional execution](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html):

```
java -jar "C:\4_USB_Relay\DenkoviRelayCommandLineTool_10.jar" DAE001DQ 4 1 status 2>&1 | find "0" && (
 java -jar "C:\4_USB_Relay\DenkoviRelayCommandLineTool_10.jar" DAE001DQ 4 1 1
) || (
  java -jar "C:\4_USB_Relay\DenkoviRelayCommandLineTool_10.jar" DAE001DQ 4 1 0
)
```

Comment: That's got it! Thanks heaps for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`System.exit(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) in your Java process to set a return code for the batch script. Then, in your batch script you can get the return code as `ERRORLEVEL` like

```
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

And an `if` might look like

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo Zero
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 echo One
```

Comment: Ok so just to confirm I didnt create the DenkoviRelayCommandLineTool_10.jar script.
So do i have to open this up in a java editor and add the System.exit(int) command?

Comment: Jar files are not scripts. You will need the source code. You can edit that with any text editor. Then you will need to recompile it and re-jar it.